# Hibernate mapping grandfathers to childs

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a model really difficult to represent with Hibernate annotations. I have tried many things but my biggest problem is that Im unable to get the grandfather id into the child entity to bring only the relevant records in the database.

This is the model:

[image: model]

The idea of this model is that everything is reusable in multiple `Main` entities.

`Main` can contain a list of `Sub1` elements not assigned to anything else, but those `Sub1` entities can also be inside of `Sub2`. Same thing happens with `Sub2`, those can be directly assigned to `Main` but also be inside of `Sub3`.

`Sub1` has a specific ordering that can be reordered later on only for that specific `Main`, so the `Sub1_Ordering` entity is generated in the logic and assigned an order outside of Hibernate.

As `Sub2` and `Sub3` can be reused in multiple `Main`, the mapping is done in a join table, there is no property inside of them that tells you where it belongs, the join table provides that information. `Sub1` can also be added to multiple `Mains` inside or not of the other entities but with different order.

This is how my entities look so far, removed some unrelated parts for simplicity:

###### Main

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "main")
  @Where(clause = "sub2_id is null")
  private Set<Sub1OrderingEntity> sub1ordering = new HashSet<>();

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "sub2_mapping",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "main_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sub2_id")
  )
  private Set<Sub2Entity> sub2 = new HashSet<>();

  @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
  @JoinTable(
      name = "sub3_mapping",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "main_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sub3_id")
  )
  private Set<Sub3Entity> sub3 = new HashSet<>();

  private String otherProperties;

}
```

###### Sub1_Ordering

```
@Entity
public class Sub1OrderingEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "main_id")
  private MainEntity main;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "sub2_id")
  private Sub2Entity sub2;

  @Column(name = "sub1_order")
  private long order;

  @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name = "sub1_id")
  private Sub1Entity sub1;

}
```

###### Sub1

```
@Entity
public class Sub1Entity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String otherProperties;

}
```

###### Sub2

```
@Entity
public class Sub2Entity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "sub2_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "main_id", referencedColumnName = "main_id")
  })
  private Set<Sub1OrderingEntity> sub1ordering = new HashSet<>();

  private String otherProperties;

}
```

###### Sub3

```
@Entity
public class Sub3Entity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "sub2_mapping",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sub3_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sub2_id")
  )
  private Set<Sub2Entity> sub2 = new HashSet<>();

  private String otherProperties;

}
```

My biggest problem right now is that, from `Sub2` I can't tell which is the `main_id` that its trying to get its records and, instead, is taking all the records assign to `Sub2`, regardless of which `Main` it belongs. Im pretty sure that more issues will arise once I have this one solved, hopefully somebody will tell me if this model will eventually work.

Comment: Why do you have a sub2_mapping table at all? You cannot map a join table between 3 entities this way - entrees for Sub3 -> Sub2Entity will be completely independent from the Main->Sub2Entity entries, which isn't what you seem to want; you might as well use two independent tables.

Answer (score 0):

You've double/triple mapped some of the FK columns when you have a circular model like this and specify both sides as unidirectional. Ie:

Sub2:

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "sub2_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "main_id", referencedColumnName = "main_id")
  })
  private Set<Sub1OrderingEntity> sub1ordering = new HashSet<>();
```

Sub1OrderingEntity:

```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "main_id")
  private MainEntity main;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "sub2_id")
  private Sub2Entity sub2;
```

The mapping within Sub2 will try to control the main_id and sub2_id columns, but they are already set and controlled through Sub1OrderingEntity's sub2 and main references. Another problem was that you have a 'main_id' column in Sub2Entity's table as a foreign key to a 'main_id' column in the Main table - but there is no such column defined. The column in Main's table will be 'id' based on the id property.

This should instead just be:

```
@Entity
public class Sub2Entity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sub2", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  private Set<Sub1OrderingEntity> sub1ordering = new HashSet<>();

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "main_id")
  private MainEntity main;

  private String otherProperties;
}
```

Note that I've also added a reference from Sub2Entity->Main to control the main_id column, and it follows the same pattern you have set for Sub1OrderingEntity. It is usually a better idea to have the foreign key reference set by the owning entity, especially if you are going to put not-null constraints on it, so that it can be found and determined when Sub2Entity are inserted: JPA providers are allowed to insert first and then update externally controlled mappings in a separate statement, so it is best not to rely on it unless you need to.

Main then would look like:

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "main")
  @Where(clause = "sub2_id is null")
  private Set<Sub1OrderingEntity> sub1ordering = new HashSet<>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "main", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Sub2Entity> sub2 = new HashSet<>();

  @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
  @JoinTable(
      name = "sub3_mapping",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "main_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sub3_id")
  )
  private Set<Sub3Entity> sub3 = new HashSet<>();

  private String otherProperties;

}
```

Sub3 would then remain unchanged from your posting, keeping sub2_mapping as a relational ManyToMany table between Sub3 and Sub2 with only the sub3_id and sub2_id fk columns. It will be up to your application how these connections to 'main' work and maintain the references if a Sub3 is only meant to reference Sub2 instances for mains referencing it (which might have been the original intent for that sub2_mapping table).

If so, get this to work and post another question as there are many other ways to map sub2_mapping.